# Unity3d. CharacterJoint is not correct

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a scene with two cubes. I want first cube to fallow rotation of second cube.
For it to work, I set `joint.targetRotation` and `slerpDrive` properties.
And it work fine. But sometimes, I noticed that it start rotating infinitely, like no `slerpDrive` is defined.
For example, to reproduce, you can see this script:

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    Rigidbody _connectedBody;
    void Awake()
    {
        var rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        var joint = gameObject.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
        joint.autoConfigureConnectedAnchor = false;
        joint.connectedBody = _connectedBody;
        joint.connectedAnchor = Vector3.zero;
        joint.anchor = Vector3.zero;

        joint.rotationDriveMode = RotationDriveMode.Slerp;

        var drive = new JointDrive()
        {
            positionSpring = 100f,
            maximumForce = float.MaxValue
        };

        joint.slerpDrive = drive;
        // joint.xDrive = drive;
        // joint.yDrive = drive;
        // joint.zDrive = drive;

        joint.targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(10, 0, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var joint = gameObject.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();

        joint.axis = Vector3.right;
    }
}
```

A cube with this script is rotating infinitely. Why? If you comment this line `joint.axis = Vector3.right;`, it stop rotating. But I do not understand why is it happening.

Comment: Why are you setting `joint.axis` every frame in `FixedUpdate()` instead of just once during `Awake()`?

Comment: @Foggzie. Yes, `joint.axis` is just for example. But it the value is always the same. I can do this `joint.axis = joint.axis` and joint will rotate. Why is it rotating?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are calling your `joint.axis = Vector3.right;` inside of `void FixedUpdate()`, `Vector3.right` is identical to `Vector3(1, 0, 0)`, meaning every update, you are giving a new position to which you are asking it to move to, giving it infinite motion.

What you should aim to do, is trigger the movement at the right moment.

I'd advise you to create "Debug bindings" with unity (basically just dedicate some binding to try stuff out) so that you have tactile feedback for your behaviours. Giving you easy access to start and stop it.

Comment: No, I do not give new position every frame. I give the same position. And it is not depend on world rotation, because it is in local space